# Simple Search and Replace use of Regular Expression

Tags: regex

So, I am adapting some code I found online to suit my needs. However, my set_pixel function has two more parameters. Since there are lots of calls to this function even doing a quick paste over would be very tedious. So, I thought this would be a good time for me to learn some simple regular expressions.

So, I have calls of this type:

`set_pixel(arg1, arg2);`

which I want to change to something like:

`set_pixel(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);`

Note: arg1 and and 2 should be preserved, whereas arg3 and arg4 are most of the time the same.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What programming language does this apply to? For example, in C#, you can use an overloaded method that takes two arguments, generates two more, and passes the whole list to a second method. Also, a little more info about what the arguments are and how you want to parse them would be helpful.

Comment: I like to mention some tools here. To create regexes I like regexdesigner from radsoft http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/.

To use the created regexes use a standard compliant tool like sed or grep. There is also a tool called grepwin that does replacing on windows very well.

Comment: Should it match `set_pixel(set_pixel(1,2), 3)`?

Comment: @JYelton: This is in C. Yes I could do an overload method, but I wanted to learn the how to use regex in search and replace sine I have never done it before.

@schoetbi: No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/set_pixel\(([^,)]*),([^,)]*)\)/
```

replace with

```
set_pixel(\1,\2,arg3,arg4)
```

Depending on the language and the situation you might be better served though with some sort of refactoring tool, default parameters, overloading etc.

Comment: I am using CodeBlocks built in Search and Replace with the Regular Expression checkbox checked, but it says I don't get any matches...

Comment: Leave out the leading and trailing slash, they are common regex delimiters in languages like JavaScript and others, but you don't need them in a development tool like CodeBlocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
s/set_pixel\(([a-zA-Z0-9_]*), ([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\);/set_pixel\($1, $2, arg3, arg4\);/g
```

with your favorite regular expression toy.  You will want to tweak the character classes based on the inputs you expect to set_pixel.